# PHP script not executed with mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my goal is to have my **PHP script executed** when a link pointing to a file or directory inside `/download` is called (e.g. when trying to call `https://example.com/download/files/file.zip` it should launch my `index.php`). My `.htaccess` inside the `/files` folder looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tested locally with XAMPP, however, everything is working just fine there.
When testing live I found out, that my script is not even executed.

Here are the differences to my local System:

- Live is running on Debian 8.9.0, I am on Windows 10
- I cannot easily access the httpd.conf (apache2.conf) on the live server
- There are **two more** .htaccess files on the live System one level down and in root

My first guess was, that there are conflicts with the other `.htaccess` files in the `/download` and root directory. However deleting those did not change anything. My script is still not executed.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Is htaccess and mod_rewrite enabled at all?

Comment: Did you delete you Browser cache after you disabeld the other htaccess files?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Presumably `index.php` is also inside the `/files` directory? Are you using other mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` files?